# I am having trouble getting a JavaScript while loop to run with a prompt and a counter

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, counter

In my program I have a prompt first that asks for the user to enter a grade and then a while loop which says while the grade does not equal -1 and an if to check if the grade is between 0 to 100. I have an else statement with a  counter called "count" incrementing by one afterwards and then printing the grade within a table.  The program then asks for the grade again until a -1 is pressed.

Here is my code.

```
 var count = 0;
 var total = 0;
 var grade;
 var avg = 0;
 grade = prompt('Enter grade(-1 to stop)');   
 while (grade != -1) {
 if (grade < -1 || > 100) {
 grade = prompt('Enter grade again');
 }
 else
 count++;  
 document.write('<tr>');
 document.write('<td>Grade ' + count  '</td>');
 document.write('<td width="50">' + grade '</td>');
 document.write('</tr>');
   
 grade = prompt('Enter grade(-1 to stop)');
 total = total + grade;    
 document.write('</table>');
 avg = total / count;
 document.write('Semester Average: ' + avg);
```

}

When a negative 1 is entered it should add of the total number of all grades, and then calculate an average by dividing the count by the total.  This will not run. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for your problem you need to use Do While instead of While else...

Do { This } while {grade = -1}

didn't understand your semester average calculating techniques. Hopefully below code will solve your problem. thanks

```js
var count = 0;
var total = 0;
var grade;
var avg = 0;


do { 
grade = prompt('Enter grade(-1 to stop)');
count++;  
document.write('<table><tr>');
document.write('<td>Grade ' + count  + ': </td>');
document.write('<td width="50"> ' + grade + ' </td>');
document.write('</tr>');


total = total + grade;    
document.write('</table>');
avg = total / count;
document.write('Semester Average: ' + avg +'<br /><br />');
}
while (grade != -1) {
    --total;
    alert("You have input -1 to stop");
 }
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. I forgot to mention that the program needs to check if the grade entered is between 0 and 100. would this be done inside of the while loop at the end or could I use a nested while loop after the first one?

Comment: it should be inside while loop or it can be used on nested loop as well depending on the condition

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the -1 one not appear inside of the table when it is entered?